# What is the best way to fetch data from database in the simplest 2D array form?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql, arrays

I have a table in my database that has around 35 columns and 100 rows , I have been trying different methods to fetch that data from the database and save it in an array to use later on for mathematical calculations, which is why I want to have a simple 2D array for later use in javascript.

I am using this code in PHP but its storing the data as a multidimensional -associative array:-

```
<?php

$hostname="localhost";
$username="root";
$password="";
$databaseName="projectd";

$connect =mysqli_connect($hostname,$username,$password,$databaseName);
$query="SELECT * FROM `TABLE 1`";
$result=mysqli_query($connect,$query);
$datas=array();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0){
    while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $datas[]=$row;
    }

} ?>
```

My array is getting stored as kind of this way:-

```
Array ( [0] => 
  Array ( [COL 1] => 0 
       [COL 2] => 1 
       [COL 3] => 2 
       [COL 4] => 3 
       ...
       [COL 31] => 30 
       [COL 32] => 31 
       [COL 33] => Total ) 
      [1] => Array ( [COL 1] => 1314001 
            [COL 2] => 0 
            [COL 3] => 0 
            [COL 4] => 0 
            [COL 5] => 0
            ...
            [COL 31] => 0 
            [COL 32] => 0 
            [COL 33] => 0 ) 
     [2] => Array ( [COL 1] => 1314002 
            [COL 2] => 0 
            Etc
```

and in javascript I am using this to fetch it:-

```
    <script>
    var user=[];
    var user = JSON.parse( '<?php echo json_encode($datas) ?>' );
    console.log( user['1']['COL 1'] );

</script>
```

So having it in this form is very difficult to carry out operations like looping and stuff. So how to simply it?

Comment: How would you like your data to look, this helps in finding the best solution.

Comment: 35 X 100 is always going to end up as a 3d array unless you use `mysqli_fetch_row
` but then you'll end up with a rather useless array of 100 Strings.